# SQl Server 'Select' Query for increment new column if conditions are met

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

i have database table like this:
[default database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdNRa.png)

i need sql select query to add incremental column value if 'Status' column is 'good' and get previous value if 'Bad'. Like this: [select query table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abfuy.png)

is there any select query to do this? i use sql server management studio for try query.

thank you for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answer, it's enough to apply windows function `SUM` with `OVER` clause with `ORDER BY` (`rows between` is not needed here):

```
declare @tbl table (id int, [Status] varchar(10));
insert into @tbl values
(1,'Good'),
(2,'Good'),
(3,'Bad'),
(4,'Good'),
(5,'Bad'),
(6,'Bad'),
(7,'Good');

select [id], 
       [status], 
       sum(case [status] when 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) [Value]
from @tbl
```

Comment: thanks michal, thats answer my question. how about if id column have same value? ex: (1,'Bad'),
(1,'Good'),
(1,'Bad'),
(1,'Good'),
(1,'Bad'),
(1,'Bad'),
(1,'Good');

Comment: @Topik Then use `over (order by id, [status])` or `over (order by id, [status] desc)`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using a reasonably new version of SQL Server, I would suggest something like the following. (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07b83/1/0) of this working).

```
SELECT
 id, 
 status, 
 sum(case when status='Good' then 1 end) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM test
ORDER by id
```

In case it's not clear, the `sum` formula will count 1 if `status='Good'` (0 otherwise) and the `over` clause tells SQL Server that the order we care about is `id` (ascending) and that we should sum from the beginning (lowest id) to the current row.

If you are using an older version of SQL Server that can't do the `ROWS BETWEEN` stuff ([pre-2012 I think](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) or if you want something that looks more like basic SQL, maybe consider something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.status, sum(case when t2.status='Good' then 1 end) as value
FROM test t1 inner join test t2
 on t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.status
ORDER BY t1.id
```

That should give you the same result and uses the same `sum` formula, but it joins each record to all the previous records in the same table. I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you solved my problem if i have same value in id column. Great!